# JavaMail Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, mailing

I'm trying to send an Email in Java but getting this error:

> org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException:
>
> SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

thats my code:

```
public static void sendHtmlEmail(String subject, String messages){

    try{
        String HOST = ...;
        final String USER = ...;
        final String PASSWORD = ...;
        String PORT = "587";
        String TO = ...;            
        String SUBJECT = "Test Mail";
        String TEXT = "This is a test message from my java application. Just ignore it";
        
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.localhost", HOST);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth",true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator()
        {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(USER, PASSWORD);
            }
        };
        
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,auth);
        
        session.setDebug(true);
        
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);    
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(USER));
        message.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        message.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        message.setText(TEXT);
        message.saveChanges();
        
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());           
        transport.close();  
        
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

I tried other solutions I found but somehow everything makes it only worse. I have the feeling something is wrong with the authentication or it is ignored cause I can use everything as password and username without getting an error like 'wrong password/username'.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Moving this suggestion back to comments, since I deleted my obviously incorrect answer...

Comment: Unfortunately, that's between you and your mail server. If you're trying to use MS Office 365, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother/client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous/d405bcb0-f40c-42fa-b1b2-477597100123 may be of some help. In essence if you're trying to use an exchange server, you may have to use a different host name, and it doesn't care about authentication. If you're on Gmail, you may have to enable the 'use less secure apps' features, however, that should result in a very different error message.

Comment: You might have better luck using the [JavaMail reference implementation](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) instead of the GNU implementation.